# How can I enter the source code of okhttp and set breakpoint on it in android studio?

Tags: android-studio, debugging, breakpoints

I am not using okhttp, instead I just use the original java.io library in Android, like InputStream. But today an exception occured when I use the `read(bytes)`method of Inputstream, and it said:

```
07-31 02:04:46.855 2388-3606/? W/System.err: java.net.ProtocolException: unexpected end of stream
07-31 02:04:46.855 2388-3606/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection$FixedLengthSource.read(HttpConnection.java:449)
07-31 02:04:46.855 2388-3606/? W/System.err:     at com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:168)
07-31 02:04:46.855 2388-3606/? W/System.err:     at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:162)
07-31 02:04:46.855 2388-3606/? W/System.err:     at com.example.test_requests.MainActivity.post_for_stream(MainActivity.java:68)
07-31 02:04:46.855 2388-3606/? W/System.err:     at com.example.test_requests.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:40)
07-31 02:04:46.855 2388-3606/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

So from the stacktrace I realize that there is some relationship between InputStream and Okhttp library in Android, though I didn't introduce the Okhttp in my project. I don't mind that, but I want to come into its source code and set breakpoint on it, so that I can know how it works as well as debugging the app more efficiently.

I can easily enter into the source code of InputStream, but I don't know where the source code of "com.android.okio.RealBufferedSource" and "com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection" are in Android Studio.

By the way I have found the source code of okio and okhttp on [googlesource](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/okhttp/+/3c938a3/okio/src/main/java/okio), **but is there a way to debug the source code on Android Studio IDE, i.e., I can set breakpoint on the code and monitor the variables within**?